# Nav menu not displaying drop down and causing format issues (HTML+CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple drop down nav menu with HTML and CSS. When I add the drop down list in, my menu goes onto two lines instead of one, and the menu doesn't appear upon hover. jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qbwyLzqj/

I cannot seem to see where my error is.

```
.menu li {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```css
.navigation {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .menu {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 70%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .menu a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      font-size: 11px;
    }
    
    #menu-item-1,
    #menu-item-2,
    #menu-item-3,
    #menu-item-4,
    #menu-item-5,
    #menu-item-6 {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .menu li {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .menu li a:hover {
      color: grey;
    }
    
    .sub-menu-2 li {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .menu li:hover .sub-menu-2 li {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
 <nav class="navigation">
    
      <ul class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    
        <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">More Info</a></li>
    
        <ul class="sub-menu-2">
          <li id="sub-menu-item-2-1"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
          <li id="sub-menu-item-2-2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li id="sub-menu-item-2-3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li id="sub-menu-item-2-4"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    
        <li id="menu-item-3"><a href="#">Designs</a></li>
    
        <li id="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    
        <li id="menu-item-5"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    
        <li id="menu-item-6"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    
    
    </nav>
```

Comment: Is the submenu supposed to display on hover over 'more info'?

Comment: Yes, sorry should have specified!

Comment: Your sub-menu-2 is nested incorrectly. It needs to be nested into the second li as in: ...
    
        <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">More Info</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-2">
          <li id="sub-menu-item-2-1"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
          <li id="sub-menu-item-2-2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li id="sub-menu-item-2-3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li id="sub-menu-item-2-4"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides fixing the layout breaking, I think you can improve it more further.

About the problem; the breaking was caused because you weren't using the `.sub-menu-2` inside it's parent `li`. I've fixed it, and added more flexibility to your code to show the sub-menu on hovering the parent list-item.

Check it out yourself. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qh5q6r81/1/)

```css
.navigation {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#menu-item-1,
#menu-item-2,
#menu-item-3,
#menu-item-4,
#menu-item-5,
#menu-item-6 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.sub-menu-2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.sub-menu-2 li {
display: block;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu-2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">

  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">More Info</a>

    <ul class="sub-menu-2">
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-1"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-4"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="menu-item-3"><a href="#">Designs</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-5"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-6"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>


</nav>
```

Hope it was helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help. Kindly mark it as accepted if you think it's the perfect answer. Happy learning :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this jsfiddle:

**Modify HTML**

```
<li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">More Info</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-2">
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-1"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-4"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

**Add Css**

```
.sub-menu-2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qh5q6r81/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code.

```css
.navigation {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#menu-item-1,
#menu-item-2,
#menu-item-3,
#menu-item-4,
#menu-item-5,
#menu-item-6 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.sub-menu-2 {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu-2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">

  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">More Info</a>

      <ul class="sub-menu-2">
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-1"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-4"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-3"><a href="#">Designs</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-5"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-6"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>


</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the dropdown `ul` inside the `li`
2. Use positioning to prevent the dropdown menu from affecting the rest of the list items

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/ecjn09Lm/1/)

```css
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#menu-item-1,
#menu-item-2,
#menu-item-3,
#menu-item-4,
#menu-item-5,
#menu-item-6 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

#menu-item-2 {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu-2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sub-menu-2 li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu-2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- nav -->
<nav class="navigation">

  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">More Info</a>

      <ul class="sub-menu-2">
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-1"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-4"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-3"><a href="#">Designs</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-5"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-6"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>


</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the updated file

```
.menu li {
  position:relative;
}
.sub-menu-2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    text-align:left;
    width:100%;

 }
```

```css
.navigation {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#menu-item-1,
#menu-item-2,
#menu-item-3,
#menu-item-4,
#menu-item-5,
#menu-item-6 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.sub-menu-2 li {
  display: none;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu-2 li {
  display: block;
  padding-left:0;
}
.sub-menu-2 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  text-align:left;
  width:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<!-- nav -->
<nav class="navigation">

  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">More Info</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-2">
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-1"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-4"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    

    <li id="menu-item-3"><a href="#">Designs</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-5"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-6"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>


</nav>
```

here is the fiddle [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbwyLzqj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<!-- nav -->
<nav class="navigation">

  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">More Info</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-2">
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-1"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li id="sub-menu-item-2-4"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>

    </li>



    <li id="menu-item-3"><a href="#">Designs</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-5"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-6"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>


</nav>


.navigation{
   width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
.menu,.menu ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
}
.menu >li{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
   padding: 5px;
  }
  .menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.menu >li ul{
  position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
      display: none;
  }
  .menu >li:hover ul{
   display: block;
  }
```

It is fiddler link aswell
https://jsfiddle.net/8engpfu1/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this...

```css
.navigation {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px; 
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.menu li {
  padding: 10px;
}
#menu-item-2 {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sub-menu-2 {
  list-style-type: none; 
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.sub-menu-2 li {
  display: none;
  padding: 0px; 
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu-2 li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">More Info</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu-2">
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-1"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu-item-2-4"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-3"><a href="#">Designs</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-5"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: none;` to the `<ul class="sub-menu-2">` to switch your menu back to one line.

```
.sub-menu-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

The menu is splitting because now you are just hiding `.sub-menu-2 li`, not `.sub-menu-2`.

Also define `z-index` to a higher value like 1000 to get the submenu on top of other elements if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'menu-item-2' like this,

```
  <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">More Info</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu-2">
    <li id="sub-menu-item-2-1"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li id="sub-menu-item-2-2"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li id="sub-menu-item-2-3"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li id="sub-menu-item-2-4"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

and add this css to your code

```
    .sub-menu-2 {
      position: absolute;
      background: #fff;
     }
```